# Get Word If substring exist in it

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

```
$Str="apartman a left join archiveapartman  on a.Id=archiveapartman.ApartmanId and a.IdDarkhast=archiveapartman.ApartmanIdDarkhast and a.ShahrdariId=archiveapartman.ApartmanShahrdariId ";
```

and I want to search `archive` in str and if it exists in str get full word `archiveapartman`.

```
$length=20;
if(strpos($Str,"archive")!==false){
     echo substr ( $Str , strpos($Str,"archive") , $length );
}
```

How can I find `$length`? Or is there a regex solution for matching this?

Comment: `strpos()` is a good place to start.... have you tried to write a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this regex

```
$re = "/archive\\w*/"; 
$str = "apartman a left join archiveapartman  on a.Id=archiveapartman.ApartmanId and a.IdDarkhast=archiveapartman.ApartmanIdDarkhast and a.ShahrdariId=archiveapartman.ApartmanShahrdariId "; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$Str="apartman left join archiveapartman";
$var = "archive";
$arrStr = explode(" ", $Str);
foreach ($arrStr as $word) {
   if (strpos($word, $var)) {
      return $word;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use the function strchr() in php.

```
$Str="apartman left join archiveapartman";
$ser='archive';
echo strchr($Str,$ser);
```

Then you have the result 'archiveapartman'. Try by yourself.

Comment: oh, yesbut if str like `apartman a left join archiveapartman  on a.Id=archiveapartman.ApartmanId and a.IdDarkhast=archiveapartman.ApartmanIdDarkhast and a.ShahrdariId=archiveapartman.ApartmanShahrdariId ` then not worked

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match all the words that start with archive and end with a space or a dot.

```
(archive[^\s\.]+)
```

You can test it on http://www.regexpal.com/

```
$Str="apartman a left join archiveapartman  on a.Id=archiveapartman.ApartmanId and a.IdDarkhast=archiveapartman.ApartmanIdDarkhast and a.ShahrdariId=archiveapartman.ApartmanShahrdariId ";

preg_match_all('/(archive[^\s\.]+)/', $Str, $results);
var_dump($results);
```

Hope this helps